# How to get Order Date + 30 Days to my woocommerce php code?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am creating a column in the main orders area for Woocommerce 3.5 that would show the customer name + 30 days added to the date the order was manually created. How do i do this with the code i have?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns','custom_column_eldest_players', 20 ); 
function custom_column_eldest_players($columns)
{
$reordered_columns = array();


foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
    $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
    if( $key ==  'order_status' ){

        $reordered_columns['skb-client'] = __( 'Customer - Expiration (30 Days)','theme_domain');
    }
}
return $reordered_columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
if ( 'skb-client' != $column ) return;

$date = 'now';
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime('+30 day', $date);


$user_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_customer_user', true );
if( ! empty($user_id) && $user_id != 0) {
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
    echo $user_data->user_login;
}

else

     echo ('<small>(<em>Guest</em>)</small> - ');
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
}
```

I expect the code to show "Guest Name - Feb 15th, 2019" if the order was placed on Jan 16th, 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ){
...
   $date = 'now';
   $date = strtotime($date);
   $date = strtotime('+30 day', $date);
...
}
```

Try this:

```
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id ){
...
   $Order = wc_get_order($post_id);
   $date = (new DateTime($Order->get_date_created()))->modify('+30 days');
...
}
```

Then something like

```
echo $date->format('M jS, Y'); //Jan 16th, 2019
```

Or however you want to display it.

Comment: This seems to have done it...awesome thanks! I was close but yet far..being a newbie lol

Comment: Does +30 days vs +30 day matter?

Comment: I don't think it does.